# What does Piccolo telling Gohan to "dodge" mean?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, meme

I have been seeing some posts on Facebook recently with Piccolo yelling at Gohan to dodge. I do not understand the reference behind it.

What incident is being referred to?

Comment: Well, in the abridged version of DBZ (by TFS), Gohan dislikes the word "Dodge" and is unable to perform correctly when ever it is yelled out. Goku mentions Gohan needs to learn how to dodge and relies on Picollo to train him that. Maybe it was because of the numerous training sessions that he hates the word.

Comment: what does that even mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes from the Team Four star parody of Dragon-Ball, and it occurs during the part where Piccolo trains Gohan to fight the Sayans

One of the things Piccolo does is tells Gohan to dodge, and then hits him.  It's a running gag throughout the series.

You can watch the parody at http://teamfourstar.com/

Answer (score 7):

This is a reference [Team Four Star's](http://teamfourstar.com/) [DragonBall Z Abridged](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6EC7B047181AD013) series.

In it, [Picollo is teaching Gohan to dodge](https://youtu.be/P6P_sXbQtgc?t=5m31s). However, [he ends up conditioned to freeze in fear of the word instead](https://youtu.be/GXeOlcctd9g?t=5m7s). This becomes one of the most popular running gags in the series.